# How to change active color of Materialize label-icon in search input

Tags: materialize

I'm new to Materialize and I'm trying to change the active color of the Search and Close icons within a search box. When active, they appear black - I want them to appear white. The examples I've found predate Materialize 1.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="search" type="search" name="search" class="light-blue darken-3 white-text">
        <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/Cormang/pen/oNvqmmM

Answer (score 0):

By default you can make your search icon active by adding `active` class to `<label>`. But it seems there is another event that makes its changes. So one of the ways to addressing this issue is using `focusin` and `focusout`.

Add a `onfocusin` to `<input>` and call a function like this :

```
function changeColorOnFocus() {
  document.querySelector(".material-icons").style.color = "white";
}
```

Use a `onfocusout` and call a function like this to change the icon's color.

Comment: I was able to add the following CSS to change the search icon, but the the "X" close icon. Still working on that one...https://codepen.io/Cormang/pen/oNvqmmM 

`nav .label-icon.active .material-icons {color: white !important;}`